# How to display popup depending on the page in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to build this chrome extension that only displays the popup when I am on a youtube video page. However, I am having a lot of difficulties doing this and used many approaches.

My latest approach is to use `chrome.action.onClicked` and check if the URL contains `https://youtube.com/watch`. Then I would use `chrome.action.setPopup` to my HTML file. This works on all pages until when I click on the extension while on a youtube video page, then it would just show on every single page.

Here is my background.js:

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {

    console.log(tab.tabId); 
    if (tab.url.includes("https://www.youtube.com/watch") == true) {
        chrome.action.setPopup({ tabId: tab.tabId, popup: "/Pages/index.html" });
    } else if (tab.url.includes("https://www.youtube.com/watch") == false) {
        chrome.action.setPopup({ tabId: tab.tabId, popup: "" });
    }
});
```

I think that it is not working because after setting the popup, that means it does not check the onClicked event anymore ([specified here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/#method-setPopup)).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's not `tab.tabId` but `tab.id`. You can check for it. And `setPopup` when `onClicked`, you have to click the extension twice will the popup show up.

Comment: This worked! Follow up question, I have been trying to stick to using Manifest V3 but it seems that using page actions with manifest V2 is more reasonable, what do you think?

Comment: I think MV3 is not a finished product, it is still iteration, and MV2 will be deprecated one day. So in the long run, MV3 is better. If you only use this technology for a short-term project, and MV2 can solve your problem better, you can use MV2 directly.

Comment: Hey I just posted another question, and you seem experienced on the topic, any chance you could go take a look?